Function Property Involving Fourier Coefficients
In my current studies on Fourier analysis, I encountered this problem while working on properties of Fourier series. The problem involves constructing a function $h$ given certain conditions on $f$ and $g$, both of which are periodic functions. Understanding this relationship is important to me because it appears to have broader implications in signal processing and the stability of solutions to differential equations.
Assume that the functions $f$ and $g$ belong to $C_0^\text{Per}([-\pi, \pi])$, with $\max_{x \in [-\pi, \pi]} |g(x)| < 1$.
Show that there exists a function $h$ such that $\hat{h}(n) = \frac{\hat{f}(n)}{1-\hat{g}(n)}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.
I believe the proof might involve constructing the function $h$ explicitly using the inverse Fourier transform and then checking its Fourier coefficients. Would using the properties of Fourier series help here?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.
